# Passing parameters for callback function

Tags: c++

I have a functionA which takes in two arguments => a callback function and an argument for the callback function. The argument of the callback could be built in type like int or the user defined type. How could I declare the functionA ?

```
eg:
void functionA(void (*handler)(TYPEA), TYPEA variableA)
{
  *handler(variableA);
}
```

The TYPEA could be the built in type or the user defined type. Should I use dynamic_casting in the handler to cast the typeA to appropriate type based on the callback function( in that case, what should typeA be?) or should I use template in this case?

Comment: Does `functionA` use the second argument for anything else than calling the `handler`?

Answer (score 4):

You can pass like this :

```
#include <iostream>

template< typename A, typename B >
void foo( A a, B b )
{
    a( b );
}

void boo1( const int p )
{
    std::cout<<"boo( " << p << " )" << std::endl;
}

void boo2( const std::string p )
{
    std::cout<<"boo( " << p << " )" << std::endl;
}


int main()
{
    foo( boo1, 3 );
    foo( boo2, "abc" );
}
```

Comment: The dereference isn't necessary before function call, and can inhibit the use of classes that overload `operator()`.

Comment: Why? Isn't it just a choice of whether you want a to be the functor itself, or a pointer to the functor?

Comment: I agree with @Chris Lutz. @user168715: If you add the `*` there, and you want to use a functor (instead of a function pointer), then you must create the functor beforehand and extract the address for the call. Without the `*`, you can create the functor in place. That is, you are making user code harder to write in the case of a functor for no particular reason.

Comment: @Chris @user168715 @David Take a note that the above example demonstrates how to implement what is asked in the question. But I will modify my answer. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 3):

If the function does not use the argument for anything other than for the callback, I would remove the callback completely:

```
// c++0x, same can be achieved with boost::function/boost::bind in c++03
void function( std::function< void ( void ) > f ) 
{
   f();
}
void callback1( int );
void callback2( Type );
//void callback3( double );
void user_code() {
   function( std::bind( callback1, 5 ) );
   function( std::bind( callback2, Type( 1, 2, 3, 4 ) );
   // function( std::bind( callback3, 5.0 );
}
```

By using a generic functor (`std::function`) that only has the arguments (none) passed from inside the `function`, you are decoupling the function from the callback. Now you can pass any type and it is up to the caller to `bind` the callback value (i.e. the callback argument is not a responsibility of `function`, nor `function` needs to know about it's type or value).

Answer (score 1):

> The TYPEA could be the built in type
>   or the user defined type.

I think, you want a function template if the type of argument to the callback-function could be anything!

```
template<class T>
void function(void (*handler)(T), T variable)
{
   handler(variable);
}
```